# Beginner help: How do I make a copy of an object and move it to a random point on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a personal web app (using javascript, html, and CSS) that lets me start a timer and as that timer counts down, a tree grows (I know, it's not original--I just didn't like any of the current offerings in the app store).

[Here is where I'm at with the app (it's usually viewed on my desktop monitor, so the garden is larger).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxLMg.png)

I've hit a roadblock in building the following functionality:

- Once the timer reaches 00:00, I want to be able to click the "Add to my garden button" and have the tree that I've grown placed at a random point on screen (in my garden). Eventually, I'd like 20+ trees planted on screen.
- I'd like to be able to start a new timer (by clicking the "Plant a new tree" button). But when I do that, I want the tree(s) that I've planted to stay where they are in my garden.

The current issue I'm running into is that the tree that I place at a random place on screen disappears when I click the "Plant a new tree" button.

Your help is both greatly needed and appreciated. Thank you a million in advance.

---

[Here](https://github.com/ccstegman/GrowingApp.git) is the repo in git if you want the see the whole thing.
Below is a piece of my Timer.js file if it helps.

```
// Get the elements
const tree = document.querySelector('.tree');
const startButton = document.querySelector('#start');
const minutesLabel = document.querySelector('#minutes');
const secondsLabel = document.querySelector('#seconds');
const addButton = document.querySelector('#add');
const countLabel = document.querySelector('#count');
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
const treeConstant = document.getElementById('treeImage');
const randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowWidth - treeConstant.width));
const randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight - treeConstant.height));
// Set the timer length (in seconds)
const timerLength = 1 * 1500;

// Initialize the timer values --------------------------------------------
let secondsRemaining = timerLength;
let intervalId;
let count = 0;

// Define a function to start the timer------------------------------------
function startTimer() {

  // Disable the button during the timer
  startButton.disabled = true;
  addButton.disabled = true;

  // Set the interval to update the timer every second
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    // Calculate the remaining minutes and seconds
    const minutes = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 60);
    const seconds = secondsRemaining % 60;

    // Update the timer display
    minutesLabel.textContent = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    secondsLabel.textContent = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');

    // Update the tree growth
    const percentComplete = 100 - (secondsRemaining / timerLength * 100);
    treeConstant.style.width = `${(percentComplete / 100) * 150}px`;
    treeConstant.style.height = `${(percentComplete / 100) * 150}px`;

    // Check if the timer is finished
    if (secondsRemaining <= 0) {

    // Stop the timer interval
    clearInterval(intervalId);

    //Reset the timer values
    secondsRemaining = timerLength;
    minutesLabel.textContent = '25';
    secondsLabel.textContent = '00';
    
    //Re-enable the button
    startButton.disabled = false;

    }
    // Decrement the remaining seconds
    secondsRemaining--;
  }, 1000);
}

// When the "Add to garden" button is pressed...
function addToGarden() {
    addToGarden.disabled = true;
    count++;
    countLabel.textContent = count;
    treeConstant.style.left = `${randomX}px`;
    treeConstant.style.top = `${randomY}px`;
}

// Attach the startTimer function to the button click event----------------
startButton.addEventListener('click', startTimer);
addButton.addEventListener('click', addToGarden);
```

Below is my html page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>The Growing App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
      </head>
      <body style="background-color: #49B265;">
        <div class="timer">
          <h1 class = "title" style="color:#FFF">The Growing App</h1>
          <div class="tree-container">
            <!--<div class="tree"></div>-->
            <img id="treeImage" src="img src="images/spacer.gif" width="305" height="312" alt="tree">
          </div>
          <div class="earth">
            <img src="brownplatformmergedtransparent.png" width="200" height = "50" alt="earth">
          </div>
          
          <div class="time">
            <span id="minutes">25</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start">Plant a new tree</button>
          </div>
        <div class="add">
            <center><button id="add">Add to my garden</button></center>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Trees in my garden: <span id="count">0</span></p>
        </div>
        <div></div>

        <script src="Timer.js"></script>
        <script src="RandomImage.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `addToGarden` doesn't create any new elements. It looks like it's using a constant `treeConstant` and changing it's position. Create an entirely new `treeConstant` element instead.

Comment: You will likely need to store your "trees" in an array or another collective construct so that it retains. I would also include the rest of your code as it is most likely relevant to giving you a decent answer. Never assume you are smarter than your call stack.

Comment: @damonholden, thanks for the feedback! Just to make sure I understand, you recommended that I include the rest of my code--are you suggesting that I insert the rest of my javascript code into the body of my question? I included the link to my git repository, but I just want to make sure I understand what you meant. Thanks!

Comment: include any relevant code. I appreciate you included the git repository, but that repo stands to change and will no longer become relevant to the question for future readers. Try and include everything required to answer the question in the question itself.

Comment: This looks interesting though, will clone your repo and debug later on.

Comment: @damonholden, Thank you! I appreciate it. I'll go ahead and add more of the js code in there, as well as the relevant html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addToGarden` function is moving the first tree. Instead, you need your function to create a new tree and move it somewhere random. Something you'll also need to do is update the `randomX` and `randomY` positions after adding the new tree to the screen so that future trees don't use the same position.

```
function addToGarden() {
    addToGarden.disabled = true;
    count++;
    countLabel.textContent = count;

    // Create new tree based off of the main tree ↓
    const newTree = treeConstant.cloneNode();

    // Give the new tree a different id ↓
    newTree.id = `tree-${count}`;

    // Set the left and top of the cloned tree ↓
    newTree.style.left = `${randomX}px`;
    newTree.style.top = `${randomY}px`;

    // Add new tree to the body (or into whatever container you need) ↓
    document.body.appendChild(newTree);

    // Create new randomX and randomY ↓
    randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowWidth - treeConstant.width));
    randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight - treeConstant.height));
}
```

More on [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Comment: Rico, thank you so much for your help. This honestly has been the biggest step forward I've been able to make in the past 3 days of trying to figure this out. For some reason, the trees are just lining up in a perfect line at the bottom of my screen. Do you know how I could randomize their placement on the screen a bit more?

Comment: No worries! It sounds like a css thing. You can try giving the cloned tree a `position: absolute` in the same place you are applying the left and top style. For example: `newTree.style.position= 'absolute';`